# What is this weird box on ChromeOS / Google Pixelbook?

Tags: user-interface, google-chrome-os, accessibility

[image: Weird Box in ChromeOS GUI]

I have a bit of an odd question. I recently bought a Google Pixelbook to use for classes and not have to carry around my big gaming laptop. I have no issues with it, I can use the stylus to take handwritten notes (better for me as I retain it better if I handwrite it), it is surprisingly powerful while running linux with Crouton CHroots, and I can use Zerotier VPN to RDP back to my gaming machine from anywhere on campus.

I have one annoyance. It is a weird translucent border that isn't actually bordering anything. The border itself when hovered over is a little darker. It doesn't prevent me from clicking on anything. It only shows up when I hover over it. It is just distracting. I've tried to describe it the best I can, but the link above is to a screenshot of what I am talking about. I'm new to StackExchange in general and trying to become more active.

Can I get rid of this box? Should I? Could it potentially be useful for something?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Gus

Comment: Do you happen to have the 'Taskbar' app from the play-store installed?  (I've observed such translucent borders, and I attribute them to the 'Taskbar' app.)